# Do I have to run rake:db migrate after each scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, localhost, scaffold

I'm in the process of creating a rails API for scheduling appointments.  I'm worrying about making a generic app version first, and then I'm going to make it in to an API, as I havn't done that before.

I've been generating 4-5 scaffolds (rails generate scaffold _____ title:string description: text)

THEN running rake dbmigrate.

When I go to view the file on my local host, while running my rails server I get this error: (unfortunately I can't post images yet with my rep)

---

No route matches [GET] "/c4cc2"

Rails.root: /Users/Jack/Desktop/Project/CareCloudAttempt2/C4CC2

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

Routes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper  HTTP Verb   Path    Controller#Action
Path / Url
end_times_path  GET /end_times(.:format)    end_times#index
POST    /end_times(.:format)    end_times#create
new_end_time_path   GET /end_times/new(.:format)    end_times#new
edit_end_time_path  GET /end_times/:id/edit(.:format)   end_times#edit
end_time_path   GET /end_times/:id(.:format)    end_times#show
PATCH   /end_times/:id(.:format)    end_times#update
PUT /end_times/:id(.:format)    end_times#update
DELETE  /end_times/:id(.:format)    end_times#destroy
start_times_path    GET /start_times(.:format)  start_times#index
POST    /start_times(.:format)  start_times#create

---

I've also tried entering the name of the routes after my URL

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :end_times

resources :start_times

resources :comments

resources :last_names

resources :first_names

end

```

I was wondering if maybe I needed to run rake db:migrate after each time I scaffold, over if it was another issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating after couple of scaffolds is fine, no need to worry there.

What is c4cc2 supposed to be there? Rails looks for resource with that name in routes but isn't finding any. What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot lol.  I was trying to point my local host at the project name THEN at the right page    EX: http://localhost:3000/projectname/routename

Comment: Yes, I'll probably have alot more to sort when I need to make this thing into an API, but Yes thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is not necessary you have run `rake db:migrate` after every `scaffold`, but you should run `rake db:migrate` before perform anything with `rails server`. If you have `pending` `migration` you may not browse your application.

But there is no problem with running `rake db:migrate` after every `scaffold`.